# `use` statement necessary for trait not used directly in this source file: why?

Tags: rust

In the code below, removing the second line will result in a compilation error saying:

```
type `std::io::net::tcp::TcpListener` does not implement any method in scope named `listen`
```

Since I am nowhere directly using Listener (even though `std` uses it internally), why do I need to specify it?

```
use std::io::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::io::{Acceptor, Listener};

fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    // ...
}

fn main() {
    let args = std::os::args();
    println!("{}", args);

    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1", 80).unwrap();

    let mut acceptor = listener.listen().unwrap();

    for stream in acceptor.incoming() {
        spawn(proc() {
            handle_client(stream.unwrap());
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a design decision of the language to require explicit `use` of traits that implement methods. For example in the following code:

```
use my::A;
use my::B;

mod my {
  pub trait A {
    fn foo(&self);
  }

  pub struct B;

  impl B {
    pub fn bar(&self) {
      println!("Called `bar`.");
    }
  }

  impl A for B {
    fn foo(&self) {
      println!("Called `foo`.");
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  // Requires "use my::B".
  let b = B;
  b.bar();

  // Requires "use my::A".
  b.foo();
}
```

I believe the motivation for this is heavily due to the fact that currently there is no seamless way to support multiple traits with the same method name. There is a lot of work being done to traits atm however https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/active/0024-traits.md.

Answer (score 0):

`Listener` is a trait, and your code uses its `listen` method, implemented by `TcpListener`

http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/io/trait.Listener.html

Comment: Yes, as stated in the question, I am aware of that. But since I am not using the trait's name myself (the std library does), I didn't expect to need it. `use` makes a name binding according to the docs (http://doc.rust-lang.org/rust.html#use-declarations). In this example, it seems like it is required even if the name is not used.

Comment: Yes, as far as the compiler is concerned, traits don't exist until imported explicitly.

Comment: After thinking a little about that, it doesn't make sense to me. For instance, I am able to use `getopts::OptGroup` without having a `use getopts::OptGroup;`. Do you have sources for what you're saying? I'm genuinely interested in this.

Comment: Yes, what I said isn't 100% correct. You can access items by typing their full name, including traits. So you could write `impl std::fmt::Show for Foo { ... }`. However, you cannot currently specify that `listener.listen()` is a call to the `listen` method of the trait `Listener` for the implementor `TcpListener`. That's why it's necessary to bring `Listener` into scope to use its methods. `OptGroups` is a struct and not subject to this limitation. Improvements in this area are planned: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/132